# My app got rejected by Apple

Tags: ios, iphone

Here I am copying my crash report.

Totally I have got four crash report. Four crash reports look same for me. I don't know where I went wrong. My app is running fine in my iOS Device

```
Incident Identifier: A1CC2129-2A56-4DCB-9E26-1681BFE0BE67
CrashReporter Key:   f3b804a3a3d5e241f0f0347e9d595143ed5ff06b
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             FindYourNeed [3226]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/33AEEC54-1ECF-4D7E-9B3F-FE7E9C99FE0C/FindYourNeed.app/FindYourNeed
Identifier:          XXXXXXXX
Version:             1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-02-16 10:53:34.34 -0800
Launch Time:         2016-02-16 10:53:27.27 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x181b2d900 0x18119bf80 0x181b2d848 0x181b14e88 0x181a1f994 0x181b15634 0x100109c2c 0x1001099b8 0x186a2bd28 0x186857e50 0x186857dcc 0x18683fa88 0x186a2bad4 0x1868628f8 0x1869f7ee8 0x1869f7104 0x186b87ae4 0x18716db20 0x1869f6e70 0x186c34c90 0x186c34854 0x18684ae84 0x1824efe20 0x181ae4efc 0x181ae4990 0x181ae2690 0x181a11680 0x182f20088 0x186888d90 0x10010f0c0 0x1815b28b8)

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
6.477880     CFNetwork                  0x000000018210584c TCP Conn 0x15fd95960 SSL Handshake DONE
6.579685     CFNetwork                  0x000000018210575c TCP Conn 0x15fd95960 starting SSL negotiation
6.579960     CFNetwork                  0x00000001821a7104 TCP Conn 0x15fd95960 complete. fd: 17, err: 0
6.580540     CFNetwork                  0x00000001821a8630 TCP Conn 0x15fd95960 event 1. err: 0



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d0140 0x1816b4000 + 115008
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181798ef8 0x181794000 + 20216
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181641dac 0x1815e0000 + 400812
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001811753f4 0x181174000 + 5108
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000181191e98 0x181174000 + 122520
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018119c248 0x181194000 + 33352
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018118ef44 0x181174000 + 110404
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000018118eb10 0x181174000 + 109328
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000018119c120 0x181194000 + 33056
9   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a11728 0x181a08000 + 38696
10  GraphicsServices                0x0000000182f20088 0x182f14000 + 49288
11  UIKit                           0x0000000186888d90 0x18680c000 + 511376
12  FindYourNeed                    0x000000010010f0c0 0x1000f4000 + 110784
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001815b28b8 0x1815b0000 + 10424

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d0b6c 0x1816b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795530 0x181794000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795020 0x181794000 + 4128

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d14fc 0x1816b4000 + 120060
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000018159494c 0x181580000 + 84300
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001815837bc 0x181580000 + 14268

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d0b6c 0x1816b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795530 0x181794000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795020 0x181794000 + 4128

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d0b6c 0x1816b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795530 0x181794000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795020 0x181794000 + 4128

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d0b6c 0x1816b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795530 0x181794000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795020 0x181794000 + 4128

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d0b6c 0x1816b4000 + 117612
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795530 0x181794000 + 5424
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795020 0x181794000 + 4128

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816b54bc 0x1816b4000 + 5308
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816b5338 0x1816b4000 + 4920
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ae4ac0 0x181a08000 + 903872
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181ae27c4 0x181a08000 + 894916
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181a11680 0x181a08000 + 38528
5   CFNetwork                       0x0000000182181434 0x1820d4000 + 709684
6   Foundation                      0x00000001824efc40 0x1823fc000 + 998464
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181797b28 0x181794000 + 15144
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181797a8c 0x181794000 + 14988
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795028 0x181794000 + 4136

Thread 8 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001816d0368 0x1816b4000 + 115560
1   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000181aeb028 0x181a08000 + 929832
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181797b28 0x181794000 + 15144
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181797a8c 0x181794000 + 14988
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181795028 0x181794000 + 4136

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000161e47bb7
    x4: 0x0000000181192e02   x5: 0x000000016fd0b4f0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000fa0
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x0000000000000002  x11: 0x0000000000000010
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000002  x14: 0x0000000016aaa2a1  x15: 0x0000000001247fff
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019fc09000  x21: 0x000000016fd0b4f0  x22: 0x000000015fd12a20  x23: 0x000000019fc14b68
   x24: 0x0000000000000001  x25: 0xf90011e56fc52d62  x26: 0x000000015fd123d0  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000001  fp: 0x000000016fd0b450   lr: 0x0000000181798ef8
    sp: 0x000000016fd0b430   pc: 0x00000001816d0140 cpsr: 0x00000000

Binary Images:
0x1000f4000 - 0x10044ffff FindYourNeed arm64  <92d127f17ff933d8a9fe7b7e562f8a2c> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/33AEEC54-1ECF-4D7E-9B3F-FE7E9C99FE0C/FindYourNeed.app/FindYourNeed
0x1200f0000 - 0x12011ffff dyld arm64  <9e98992ceed735e2ac4784cb28efe7c1> /usr/lib/dyld
0x18111c000 - 0x18111dfff libSystem.B.dylib arm64  <c4cd04b37e5f34698856a9384aefff40> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x181120000 - 0x181173fff libc++.1.dylib arm64  <d430d0ad16893b76bbc52468f65d5906> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x181174000 - 0x181193fff libc++abi.dylib arm64  <1c0a8ef87e8c37b2a577dc1a44e2b16e> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x181194000 - 0x181500fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64  <da8e482b3e7d3c40a798a0c86a3d6890> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x181504000 - 0x181508fff libcache.dylib arm64  <242f50f854a1301fa6f76b4531101238> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x18150c000 - 0x181517fff libcommonCrypto.dylib arm64  <962b6da2f76d3b22afb83adeb2b030ef> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x181518000 - 0x18151bfff libcompiler_rt.dylib arm64  <516b8400a98f3a4fb8f82780faca4b31> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x18151c000 - 0x181523fff libcopyfile.dylib arm64  <c027b29d770e3a5e83aa48463916d3ed> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x181524000 - 0x18157ffff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64  <f3daba6e74753ddc9d7a3df953621d46> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x181580000 - 0x1815aefff libdispatch.dylib arm64  <aa5aa53cebb13e23a840ac24e4380c81> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1815b0000 - 0x1815b2fff libdyld.dylib arm64  <217f387a9d803ad1b8543fbcae5c8ec0> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1815b4000 - 0x1815b4fff liblaunch.dylib arm64  <aec3e1f1241e33a888763b2b3d54fc16> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x1815b8000 - 0x1815bcfff libmacho.dylib arm64  <c0a027eb0fdf34c4948a7a579754bb94> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x1815c0000 - 0x1815c1fff libremovefile.dylib arm64  <2fb2b791a3453c019640b22cee6a0c00> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x1815c4000 - 0x1815dafff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64  <c0b57534f20e3488a77be968b06665d7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1815dc000 - 0x1815ddfff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64  <294794ae7146331c8fd65a1ba652e7a4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1815e0000 - 0x18165ffff libsystem_c.dylib arm64  <880a61b1eb96367f9bd7af9ec768c89b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x181660000 - 0x181663fff libsystem_configuration.dylib arm64  <03109db3910b3d1db039296a8dcf3a6f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
0x181664000 - 0x181666fff libsystem_containermanager.dylib arm64  <fe2c6b6a57b6325887f02a3c867d36bf> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_containermanager.dylib
0x181668000 - 0x181669fff libsystem_coreservices.dylib arm64  <4bfbf0b2029f31299048d8aa82f50cf4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib
0x18166c000 - 0x181682fff libsystem_coretls.dylib arm64  <a920142634313a95ad276a8e7ce041fc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coretls.dylib
0x181684000 - 0x18168cfff libsystem_dnssd.dylib arm64  <aad8313dc34138e58674de8b37c8f823> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x181690000 - 0x1816b1fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64  <c38ce7aacdf33d4081b7a526c8c3034e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1816b4000 - 0x1816d5fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64  <13195140aba33e139925c949e4ec1e14> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1816d8000 - 0x1816f4fff libsystem_m.dylib arm64  <784c81a596ec3863bbb18d2c6d57d1ce> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
0x1816f8000 - 0x181711fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64  <d540cfed29133811b05483d34c1d1b12> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x181714000 - 0x181773fff libsystem_network.dylib arm64  <8668f3c7d2583a858e982e431ff0029b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x181774000 - 0x18177cfff libsystem_networkextension.dylib arm64  <9294202d3e963025b416a89d70a0a9f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib
0x181780000 - 0x18178afff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64  <dd38cc9e177a31f1820c306f9a5cdb90> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x18178c000 - 0x181791fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64  <7ad36a3f683830338c1023238ee36e2d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x181794000 - 0x18179cfff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64  <699f755441ea3a8da43569da86269469> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1817a0000 - 0x1817a2fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib arm64  <fe96a44b2ade3550a73fbec1d1766da4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x1817a4000 - 0x1817b4fff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64  <6168fd469cbd3f4494d9a17c2128acb1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1817b8000 - 0x1817bdfff libunwind.dylib arm64  <667befcaf5f339fb885e77ce99512fca> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x1817c0000 - 0x1817c0fff libvminterpose.dylib arm64  <0735d1ebbd123718a8f17eb113615d6d> /usr/lib/system/libvminterpose.dylib
0x1817c4000 - 0x1817e9fff libxpc.dylib arm64  <b4614a68d1cb32a99ff638ddb1181ff4> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1817ec000 - 0x1819f1fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64  <5c1540546de5350ab314c1d4c8a46d1b> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1819f4000 - 0x181a05fff libz.1.dylib arm64  <c46172ce833d398a8f1b54d22a4aaeaf> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x181a08000 - 0x181d80fff CoreFoundation arm64  <121118a9a44d3518b99f3ebfd8806f69> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x181d84000 - 0x181d94fff libbsm.0.dylib arm64  <bfee5e310ce439f0912635ac0bdbcaef> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x181d98000 - 0x181d98fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64  <913105a7ca583fed80e6b6329387bd34> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x181d9c000 - 0x181e0cfff IOKit arm64  <3183206b8f683af29d373817ca5ce34d> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x181e10000 - 0x181e2ffff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64  <c9c425b7cc243ecfbb96c6b98a6737f9> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x181e30000 - 0x181f1afff libxml2.2.dylib arm64  <83e0d7a7234a3d93b70b33c650cce1c5> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x181f1c000 - 0x181f89fff Security arm64  <74474ceb538f35bdac96f3a9b7c9c2fa> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x181f8c000 - 0x181fe5fff SystemConfiguration arm64  <ede85de1bd2830518ea2caac42bad651> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x181fe8000 - 0x1820d0fff libsqlite3.dylib arm64  <ac049ebda5c534d7a81fff7ff8924192> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1820d4000 - 0x182360fff CFNetwork arm64  <479946ecd173383d803077b338576727> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x182364000 - 0x182371fff libbz2.1.0.dylib arm64  <736f0f9f7b003dcbb91351472cedfd49> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x182374000 - 0x18238dfff liblzma.5.dylib arm64  <6a0f886fe05d3250a030dd9256b14c08> /usr/lib/liblzma.5.dylib
0x182390000 - 0x1823aafff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64  <8315a6fa429b3bc58da2a8d1cd259d61> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1823ac000 - 0x1823d6fff libarchive.2.dylib arm64  <2558513a9240332998aa09cdbf49f3ec> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x1823d8000 - 0x1823f6fff libextension.dylib arm64  <b59c905587a63c9da06bfc8594ad8ae8> /usr/lib/libextension.dylib
0x1823f8000 - 0x1823f9fff liblangid.dylib arm64  <49ce8afa64a033328e76f25af85ff4c4> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x1823fc000 - 0x182669fff Foundation arm64  <9c53ce054a5630c98001ecd8fd71080a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x18266c000 - 0x182717fff libBLAS.dylib arm64  <c534306ddf9e3b90b25e1b66695b0dd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x182718000 - 0x182a7dfff libLAPACK.dylib arm64  <ca2b7c7ec1bb30b98c037998b26e01f2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x182a80000 - 0x182cdcfff vImage arm64  <a3390b9bac5135369964865d050a9b95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x182ce0000 - 0x182d02fff libvMisc.dylib arm64  <1dee62445ded325a93cfca54303bd378> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x182d04000 - 0x182d18fff libLinearAlgebra.dylib arm64  <0623251016ad33349829e232f4624c7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
0x182d1c000 - 0x182d2bfff libSparseBLAS.dylib arm64  <5d1851c74bd63cb1a1b6e4dfe8dc59cc> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparseBLAS.dylib
0x182d2c000 - 0x182d98fff libvDSP.dylib arm64  <7a83ca773be63bbbb33a8e8d1c2da9b7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x182d9c000 - 0x182d9cfff vecLib arm64  <9008c7ee8a703d6faa091456a8990715> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x182da0000 - 0x182da0fff Accelerate arm64  <234dafe4fb09333a8bd23b74dff5670e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x182da4000 - 0x182f11fff CoreGraphics arm64  <b225beb40caf3521ad8af13986c9e25e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x182f14000 - 0x182f28fff GraphicsServices arm64  <9c0d8d96ee9a3abaa9ca2c1c83291ccd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x182f2c000 - 0x182f74fff AppSupport arm64  <02b59c1c8da334a9852a3aa9bab98c07> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x182f78000 - 0x183039fff MobileCoreServices arm64  <afb0867c27e237b08d6fb64e1c44db59> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x18303c000 - 0x183084fff BaseBoard arm64  <c5af56c0a45f3308932ffa68e609ccd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x183088000 - 0x183093fff AssertionServices arm64  <6be337b9a4ad3c72b1a9f5e48ac329db> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x183094000 - 0x1830b5fff BackBoardServices arm64  <1098f9a35be63f4798089c25d613565c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x1830b8000 - 0x1830bbfff MobileSystemServices arm64  <7eb26bea09f53c1c9e8d732f9f8ba026> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x1830bc000 - 0x1830f1fff FrontBoardServices arm64  <c1c5ada9ceb03917892e043fee80857f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
0x1830f4000 - 0x1830fefff UserNotificationServices arm64  <e8dcb070485f38b699ef6b5decf244d0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserNotificationServices.framework/UserNotificationServices
0x183100000 - 0x183125fff SpringBoardServices arm64  <eda15d90c5b4335299934d2c5fbcbede> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x183128000 - 0x183137fff MobileKeyBag arm64  <ed676cb30f5b38c8a4b00b84e66f216d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x183138000 - 0x18313efff IOSurface arm64  <5cb861f068073646a7e4f594baeb3dac> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x183140000 - 0x18314cfff liblockdown.dylib arm64  <80c801d17a24305a9f55a53ba66d1e1a> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x183150000 - 0x18315ffff CrashReporterSupport arm64  <c01e9de574133fdf90a9526fc10457be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x183160000 - 0x183162fff IOSurfaceAccelerator arm64  <799c7fc9ad973988a2d974d16a1a8618> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurfaceAccelerator.framework/IOSurfaceAccelerator
0x183164000 - 0x1831a5fff AppleJPEG arm64  <244899ffb13030d09097bcb67d1c0f0b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleJPEG.framework/AppleJPEG
0x1831a8000 - 0x1834c9fff ImageIO arm64  <1dcba4911a183ca38528d0b4db7338a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1834cc000 - 0x1834d0fff TCC arm64  <785cd2d136fd3300a63f0c9b65a69b8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x1834d4000 - 0x1834d9fff AggregateDictionary arm64  <df37471257ac3732924711a6cc7aba99> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x1834dc000 - 0x1834e9fff PowerLog arm64  <af9c5f3d9b3e3a02ab7c00bf83a3b0c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PowerLog.framework/PowerLog
0x1834ec000 - 0x183549fff libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib arm64  <ec797d85e16f343a9b5d39ee63204090> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
0x18354c000 - 0x18355efff CommonUtilities arm64  <8f96b3d9ea333d20985ec6f5d77a5946> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x183560000 - 0x183577fff libcompression.dylib arm64  <fecdce66a127392f968b6b0fe72b819c> /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
0x183578000 - 0x1837c2fff CoreData arm64  <5d453eca9d25369fbe1152ec7aa44b1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1837c4000 - 0x1837c8fff libCoreVMClient.dylib arm64  <05aad56f45e13172ad7a5d9fc156ccd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x1837cc000 - 0x1837d0fff IOAccelerator arm64  <7889e7b1f9ad30f19539dacc3a4e1a48> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x1837d4000 - 0x1837d5fff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib arm64  <a1731d84b8ec3cc78b140153b1f97694> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x1837d8000 - 0x1837dbfff libCoreFSCache.dylib arm64  <f67161256ed732219f5599270648e012> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
0x1837dc000 - 0x183822fff libGLImage.dylib arm64  <d533fa1b7b5f3f1b9a38a8aa0d4b80c4> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x183824000 - 0x18382efff libGFXShared.dylib arm64  <102edb9f54593c12b761398991a2878f> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x183830000 - 0x183836fff IOMobileFramebuffer arm64  <33cde30cbca83a60957157185c6fbe45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x183838000 - 0x183838fff libmetal_timestamp.dylib arm64  <56af01754111343da708ce2963dc993c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/libmetal_timestamp.dylib
0x18383c000 - 0x183882fff Metal arm64  <2c6f99dd5edb3b4b9bb8233c120dd370> /System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Metal
0x183884000 - 0x18388efff OpenGLES arm64  <cfb6dabfaa5c32bb84bfbb8c31fb2e06> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x183890000 - 0x1838b0fff CoreVideo arm64  <653d4a02c4443e79b9dedc88fec89b4d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x1838b4000 - 0x1838b6fff OAuth arm64  <ea5d8026af173483918a09c303104746> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x1838b8000 - 0x1838effff Accounts arm64  <70308607c9873d7d827735c98303ef29> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1838f0000 - 0x1839e2fff libiconv.2.dylib arm64  <fadcb98c1c1b356c84f83a0405014023> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x1839e4000 - 0x183aa0fff CoreAudio arm64  <7cc6066c806039bca940716231637628> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x183aa4000 - 0x183aa7fff UserFS arm64  <8e3c32ed612f310f8253a9fc3ef365f4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
0x183aa8000 - 0x183b95fff CoreMedia arm64  <6ad8fea7e3033ea8ae61060f5e19f6b6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x183b98000 - 0x183ba0fff libcupolicy.dylib arm64  <86ae97c485ea3d27880d4075a0378a12> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
0x183ba4000 - 0x183c16fff CoreTelephony arm64  <9d5c070b5f1536399d8dc4583ef8240e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x183c18000 - 0x183cf8fff libFontParser.dylib arm64  <fc643a21296736b5b2b61481d61a306e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/libFontParser.dylib
0x183cfc000 - 0x183d7cfff VideoToolbox arm64  <be617809dd93333ab50db1e22fec1c11> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x183d80000 - 0x183d80fff FontServices arm64  <bbec62921db432008ff91dbecc9f5f63> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FontServices.framework/FontServices
0x183d84000 - 0x183eaffff CoreText arm64  <d116fec0cc2136cb9ccff9f0b77c0427> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x183eb0000 - 0x183ec1fff ProtocolBuffer arm64  <ae731c8324143bd0b1fa42c083cd1bb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x183ec4000 - 0x183eebfff PersistentConnection arm64  <f891b056a74d3aecbc515a5dd93a182a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x183eec000 - 0x183ef3fff DataMigration arm64  <4d957c76b4a535349f065e4e26e32a75> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x183ef4000 - 0x18421afff AudioToolbox arm64  <732b31e0907438e38393c1401a2326b8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x18421c000 - 0x1843befff QuartzCore arm64  <b18fd2d29c78340581fc516141c52a36> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1843c0000 - 0x1843c6fff Netrb arm64  <89a82d19bfa832c3be2b4d8bcdaf04c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
0x1843c8000 - 0x1843d9fff libcmph.dylib arm64  <788e21990d61308cb3a8eeac6f28cda9> /usr/lib/libcmph.dylib
0x1843dc000 - 0x1843f7fff libmis.dylib arm64  <75c4bd30d45838a7a276a4c687d9676c> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x1843f8000 - 0x184479fff LanguageModeling arm64  <8f0afc836b7c31a4ba004f9ba495159c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x18447c000 - 0x18453cfff ManagedConfiguration arm64  <14f012126fcc31b985744406ffabdc4c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x184540000 - 0x184557fff libmarisa.dylib arm64  <5a00674979ab31b1a216a56c1f60458e> /usr/lib/libmarisa.dylib
0x184558000 - 0x18461ffff ProofReader arm64  <1128b6d743133c6b80b762645c0a9e54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x184620000 - 0x184626fff MediaAccessibility arm64  <1ad85ca5a76f3e6692df4fbb1b7d1019> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
0x184628000 - 0x184637fff MobileAsset arm64  <10c161389d7039a0a01a8a338f349fae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x184638000 - 0x184690fff ColorSync arm64  <9e5c88dec3743290b78e9df8ec74492c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ColorSync.framework/ColorSync
0x184694000 - 0x1846dffff MetalPerformanceShaders arm64  <5b5f3ef3b3503289aad9b60b08268721> /System/Library/Frameworks/MetalPerformanceShaders.framework/MetalPerformanceShaders
0x1846e0000 - 0x184b0cfff FaceCore arm64  <c081228025fe3e6bb800430051181fb4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
0x184b10000 - 0x184b8bfff Quagga arm64  <668639b359dd35b99fd432f187422807> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
0x184b8c000 - 0x184d2efff CoreImage arm64  <b9d5db7c62583ce5aa67a929c32ecbdd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x184d30000 - 0x184d61fff TextInput arm64  <99990781f4e23fa4a7603033c12e7880> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x184d64000 - 0x184d6efff libAccessibility.dylib arm64  <925fa2dd49eb3ae9b2457f3bb3a56dc9> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x184d7c000 - 0x185360fff JavaScriptCore arm64  <8734a54ac2923d9b9957c1a4b2cbc9eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x18554c000 - 0x1864f3fff WebCore arm64  <31d224ffb1b03ef3aef621656fa6eb83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x1864f4000 - 0x18651dfff libxslt.1.dylib arm64  <e6a0f1496d6d33a2b64339fa29c76daa> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x186520000 - 0x1865fdfff WebKitLegacy arm64  <c3ad1cf573fc37f79202166b2a8e4de2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKitLegacy.framework/WebKitLegacy
0x186600000 - 0x1866b7fff CoreUI arm64  <29d544d0b53e394aabcfc44fa72488ce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
0x1866b8000 - 0x1866ddfff DictionaryServices arm64  <f39018d31eeb3d35b820df074d18f54b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x1866e0000 - 0x1866e0fff HangTracer arm64  <231afe8a1d2e31339c291c80e7c00bb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x1866e4000 - 0x186732fff PhysicsKit arm64  <9ba1d2dbac4d34b2a984036875c03449> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
0x186734000 - 0x18680afff UIFoundation arm64  <9f36816edf3139ecbced1102ad25421f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x18680c000 - 0x187404fff UIKit arm64  <1ed8c851528d340980eaf65410c76c18> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x187408000 - 0x187429fff CoreBluetooth arm64  <7db7b40d76183ecdb7347f3c71a5a2ef> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/CoreBluetooth
0x18742c000 - 0x187451fff DataAccessExpress arm64  <4a4b7cfe1bff3250a33935a7cf001f77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x187454000 - 0x18746dfff NetworkStatistics arm64  <e09050a83e2c34eb9fcaa4b53c8a0173>
```

Here I have deleted some code (In Binary Images) because Stack Overflow questions can only be 30000 characters.

Comment: Since you are not trying to find solution? R U srs?

Answer (score 2):

You have to decode this crash log. In Xcode you should be logged in to your apple account and get this crash log from there.  Xcode will use your archive ti decode crash log and  this line:

```
12  FindYourNeed                    0x000000010010f0c0 0x1000f4000 + 110784
```

will be pointing to some code of yours which has a problem. In Xcode click menu `Window/Organizer` than "Crashes" tab. Select your app and locate this crash log (it should be decoded).

Alternative is to locate in archive the symbol files and use `atos` tool to covert this address: `0x000000010010f0c0` to  specyfic line number in your code.

```
atos -o <archive location>/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FindYourNeed 0x000000010010f0c0
```

To match symbol file to this crash log use this command:

```
 xcrun dwarfdump --uuid <archive location>/Contents/Resources/DWARF/FindYourNeed
```

this should print value `UUID: 92d127f1-7ff9-33d8-a9fe7b7e562f8a2c`

---

You have to check this crash log on machine which you did a build and send it to Apple (you need symbols file generated during build). If you did that, than Xcode should alter this line of crash log with specific file name and line number.

When you have file name and line number remember to checkout the code to vertion which you used for this build.

Comment: Yes I have got crash report by clicking Crash Tab from window.I am unable to find in which line my code got crashed ..Could you please say what to do next..As this is my First Application. sorry to say i don't know how to use atos tool

Comment: See update! Or find a symbols file for build you send to apple and go with `atos` procedure.